# Ruby on Rails form param is missing or the value is empty. But value is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to submit a form in ruby on rails that i made, but keep getting de next error.
Ruby on Rails form: param is missing or the value is empty

my form

```
<%= form_for @test do |f| %>     
  <div class="field"> 
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br> 
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"> 
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my controller

```
  def new
    @test = Test.new
  end

  def create
    @test = Test.new(allow_params)
    if @test.save
      redirect_to 'test/index'
    else
      render 'test/new'
    end
  end

  private

  def allow_params
    params.require(:last_name).permit(:first_name) 
  end
```

my routes

```
resources :test
  get 'test/index'
  get 'test/new'
  get 'test/create'
  post '/tests' => 'test#create'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attributes are within the `test`label, so here you should go :

```
def allow_params
  params.require(:test).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```

Comment: Why the bang on permit? why the attributes within an array?

Comment: the bang was a bad mistake, sorry about that. the array is okay, extraneous indeed

Comment: Hi ben, when i put the code in i get a new error wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Comment: It's okay, but maybe superfluous, take a look to the [method definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c1014e435d26db867b2c15b74c9ef47ccff38edb/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L522).

Comment: @Peter-Jan van Broekhuizen which is ? See the edits Sebastian rightly advised

Comment: @Ben what should the code look like? i can figure it out

Comment: it should look exactly as it's shown; otherwise i would not have answered it, and sebastian would not have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Look, this is what you form posts when you click submit:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"...", "test"=>"first_name"=>"poldo", "last_name"=>"de poldis"},"commit"=>"Create"}
```

As you can see `first_name` and `last_name` are inside an hash as value of a key called `test`. Indeed your function `allow_params` expects something like this

```
last_name: {first_name: 'poldo'}
```

as you can see the param (`last_name`) is missing, because is inside `test`!
The right way is as Ben answered:

```
  params.require(:test).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
```

To understand better how strong parameters works I suggest to you to check this page [Api doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) or even better [The latest version ofthe official manual](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Comment: And as I can see in your live example ` params.require(:test).permit!(test: [:first_name, :last_name])` is wrong too because this `test: [` does not exists